# Creating sub system and category for Cocoa Lumberjack os logging

Tags: cocoalumberjack

Apple documentation says it provides a way to define a category under a subsystem for filtering logs specific to that category (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/1643744-os_log_create?language=objc). I looked up the Cocoa Lumberjack library but there doesn't seem to be a way to create sub categories. Are there any alternatives we could use with Cocoa Lumberjack library to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add the category and a subsytem used in os_log for Cocoa Lumberjack. You can add a subsystem and a category like in this example:

```swift
/// Initialization
for category in LoggerCategory.allCases {
    let logger = DDOSLogger.init(subsystem: "com.yourname", category: category.rawValue)
    logger.logFormatter = CustomLoggingFormatter(category: category)
    DDLog.add(logger)
}

enum LoggerCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    case test
    
    var index: Int {
       return Self.allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!
    }

}

/// Custom logging formatter that filters messages by the category that is provided in the context
class CustomLoggingFormatter: NSObject, DDLogFormatter {

    let category: LoggerCategory
    
    /// Intializer for custom logger that filters out messages with the provided category
    /// - Parameter category: Category that will be filtered (shown for provided category)
    init(category: LoggerCategory) {
        self.category = category
    }
    
    func format(message logMessage: DDLogMessage) -> String? {
        guard logMessage.context == category.index else { return nil }
        
        return "\(logMessage.message)"
    }
}
```

```swift
// Usage:
DDLogWarn("Your message", context: 1) // context for filter
// Output in console
2020-12-16 16:44:17.899062+0100 App[1234:1234] [test] Your message
```

[Source, see merge request and discussion](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/pull/1039/files#diff-bda5488806af67db66134f891c4cf14aa0f76e90cb01c9ad8ae7325c892a8458)